# Why won't IIS serve my website? - 404 Page Not Found

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, iis, asp.net, http

Built a brand new server, with a fresh copy of Windows Server 2003 x86 Enterprise Edition w/SP2.
Installed the .NET Framework 1.1, 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0
Added the "Domain Controller" and "Application Server" roles.
Created a new website, pointed it to a local directory: `C:\Inetpub\angryoctopus.net\`
Added the appropriate host headers: [angryoctopus.net](http://angryoctopus.net/), [www.angryoctopus.net](http://www.angryoctopus.net/), TCP port 80, all IPs
Moved the website content into the local directory.
Configured the default document in IIS: [Default.aspx](http://www.angryoctopus.net/Default.aspx)
Enabled ASP.NET for this website, and set it to the correct version: 2.0.50727
Configured the zone angryoctopus.net in DNS. [Tested DNS lookup here](http://www.websitepulse.com/help/tools.php) to ensure DNS was functional.
Opened website in VS 2008 and re-built (and debugged) to ensure the content was functional.

I can clearly see that IIS is responding normally, by [browsing directly to my server's IP address](http://173.14.245.129/). Since this does not use the angryoctopus host header, the default website is displayed instead: the "Under Construction" page.

And yet, after all of this, [angryoctopus.net](http://angryoctopus.net/) still returns 404.

Does anybody know what could be wrong? What troubleshooting steps have I forgotten? Is there a command-line diagnostic that might provide more information?

**EDIT:** I should add that this server *is* behind a firewall with redundant wan connections, and that it's local IP address is different: 10.0.0.10 I don't know if this has any effect, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Here is a snippet of the log file for this website. This event occured when I clicked on the [`Default.aspx`](http://www.angryoctopus.net/Default.aspx) link above. The log doesn't seem to record any events for the other links...

```
2010-05-11 20:31:26 W3SVC1635707849 10.0.0.10 GET /Default.aspx - 80 - 10.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+Creative+AutoUpdate+v1.40.01) 404 2 0
2010-05-11 20:31:43 W3SVC1635707849 10.0.0.10 GET /Default.aspx - 80 - 10.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+Creative+AutoUpdate+v1.40.01) 404 2 1260
```

**EDIT 2:** I have confirmed that the website *does* in fact [serve plain HTML pages](http://www.angryoctopus.net/AdSamplePage.htm) without any problems. The error only occurs on ASP pages (including the ASP page in the center IFrame in that link).

**EDIT 3:** Here is a screenshot of my Web Service Extensions in IIS:
[image]

Why aren't ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 4.0 in the list? They show up just fine in the website properties:
[image]

Comment: I can't help with the question, other than ask what's in the server logs, but I am wondering why this public facing web server is a domain controller.

Comment: @John Gardeniers: Because I'm too cheap to build more than one server in my house. :-) This server is needed for both my and my wife's buisnesses. It needs to provide the domain-level security, plus a ton of storage space (4TB) for my wife's photo shoots (~5GB each), and host our website(s). We prefer to host the websites manually, since we like the level of control, as well as the development freedom it provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the log file, you are getting a 404.2 error message. This typically means "web service extension lockdown policy blocked the request".

Since you are trying to load an ASPX page, go into IIS manager and go to the "Web Service Extensions" category. Ensure that the ASP.Net extensions are Allowed.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this! Thanks. You may have pointed me in the right direction, but this has made the problem a little more complex. See EDIT 3 above for details.

Comment: Fixed it! I needed to add the appropriate Web Service Extension DLLs to the WebService Extension list for ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0. Then I had to add permissions to the folder `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files` giving both `LOCAL USER` and `NETWORK USER` full access to `This folder, subfolders, and files`. Everything works like a charm! Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.